# Given $\sum a_n $ convergent, are $\sum n^{1/n} a_n$ and $\sum a_n/({1+ |a_n|})$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $\sum a_n $ be a convergent series. Is
>
> 1. $\sum n^{1/n} a_n$ convergent?
> 2. $\sum a_n/({1+ |a_n|})$ convergent?
>
> If not, provide examples in the contrary.

I feel like 1 is maybe convergent, however I cannot seem to prove it or come up with an example to contradict. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean with the second series? I assume you do not mean $a_n/1$ since then you would just write $a_n$?

Comment: For the first one we have by AM-GM that $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq{}(1+...+1)/n=1$ and thus it converges.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1025896/42969 for #1 and  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193486/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/348910/42969 for #2.

Comment: @MartinR, I did not realize that both are already answered before. Thank you for providing links. Do you think we should close the posting as duplicate?

Comment: @SangchulLee: I think so. (As a gold-badge holder you can add *both* other threads as duplicate targets.)

Comment: @MartinR, That functionality is exactly what I wondered. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no assumption that $a_n$ is non-negative, one must be careful when jumping to the conclusion.

1. Notice that $n^{1/n}$ is monotone and bounded on $n\geq 3$. So we can apply [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test) to show that $\sum n^{1/n} a_n$ is convergent.
2. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348910/if-sum-a-n-is-a-convergent-series-what-about-sum-fraca-n1a-n) for a counter-example. A nuking-a-fly argument is to utilize the following theorem:

   > **Theorem.** Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the following property:
   >
   > $$ \forall (a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \ : \quad \sum a_n \text{ converges} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sum f(a_n) \text{ converges}. $$
   >
   > Then there exist $\delta > 0$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = cx$ on $(-\delta, \delta)$.